# Pixel Width of the text in a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I need to draw a UILabel striked through. Therefore I subclassed UILabel and implemented it as follows:

```
@implementation UIStrikedLabel

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextFillRect(context,CGRectMake(0,rect.size.height/2,rect.size.width,1));
}
@end
```

What happens is that the the UILabel is striked through with a line being as long as the whole label, but the text can be shorter.
Is there a way to determine the length of the text in pixels, such that the line can appropriately be drawn?

I'm also open to any other solutions, if known :)

Best,
Erik

Answer (score 197, accepted):

NSString has a [sizeWithAttributes:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithAttributes:) method that can be used for this. It returns a CGSize structure, so you could do something similar to the following to find the width of the text inside your label.

### iOS 7 and higher

```
CGSize textSize = [[label text] sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[label font]}];

CGFloat strikeWidth = textSize.width;
```

### iOS <7

Prior to iOS7, you had to use the [sizeWithFont:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString%5FUIKit%5FAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:) method.

```
CGSize textSize = [[label text] sizeWithFont:[label font]];

CGFloat strikeWidth = textSize.width;
```

UILabel has a font property that you can use to dynamically get the font details for your label as i'm doing above.

Comment: sizeWithFont is deprecated since iOS7.

Use CGSize textSize = [string sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]}]; instead.

Comment: You can also use `label.attributedText.size`.

Answer (score 71):

A better solution, here in **Swift**:
**Update:**
For `Swift 3/4`:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
// in any function
testLabel.text = "New Label Text"
let width = testLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width
let height = testLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height
print("width:\(width), height: \(height)")
```

Old Answer:

```
yourLabel?.text = "Test label text" // sample label text
let labelTextWidth = yourLabel?.intrinsicContentSize().width
let labelTextHeight = yourLabel?.intrinsicContentSize().height
```

Comment: is this ios 7 compatible?

Comment: This option is significantly faster

Comment: Newb question.. Don't you need a width/height to create a label though? At least that's where I am. Trying to find the width of the text that I'm creating a label with.  `let sanskritLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 120, sanskritStringSize.width, sanskritStringSize.height))`

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Try it

```
NSDictionary *attrDict = @{NSFontAttributeName : [GenericUtility getOpenSansRegularFontSize:12]};
CGSize stringBoundingBox = [selectedReservationModel.DateLabel sizeWithAttributes: attrDict];
lblDeliveryDateWidth = stringBoundingBox.width;
```