# NSString text pixel length

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

How to know how much pixels my text is taking in a UILabel ?
I want to insert a small picture in between text.
Can be usefull to adjust my label width.

Comment: In measuring text in AppKit, there are no such things as pixels. The string-measurement methods give you their answers in points. One point is 1/72 of an inch. Currently, these numbers are actually pixels because the window's scaling factor is always 1. Someday, this will change: The scaling factor will reflect the resolution of the screen, and string measurements will be in points, as intended. Quartz Debug lets you change the scaling factor; you can use this to make sure you're ready for that day.

Comment: but it does give me the distance i need to resize my label and put my imageview just after it ?!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few methods in NSString added by UIKit that can give you the dimensions of the string if it were to be drawn.  The full reference is [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).  The methods you care about are probably these:

- sizeWithFont:
- sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:
- sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:
- sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:
- sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:

Answer (score 2):

`-[NSString sizeWithFont:]` is part of [`NSString(UIStringDrawing)`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this post [Pixel Width of the text in a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340667/pixel-width-of-the-text-in-a-uilabel)