# How to determine the length of the text in a UITextfield

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I have a UITextField from which I'd like to determine the width of the entered text.

The bounds property has just the size of the Textfield but not of the text

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
CGFloat width =  [aTextField.text sizeWithFont:aTextField.font].width;
```

Answer (score 8):

Now that `sizeWithFont:` is deprecated in iOS 7.0 use

```
CGFloat width =  [tf.text sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName:tf.font}].width;
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithAttributes:

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for character count it is this

```
int textLength = [someTextField.text length]
```

If you are looking for pixel width try this

```
CGSize size = [someTextField.text sizeWithFont:someTextField.font];
//size.width contains the width
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3.0:

```
let size = aTextField.attributedText?.size()
let height = size.height
let width = size.width
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize size = [myTextField.text sizeWithFont:myTextField.font];
```

Documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:

Answer (score 0):

Does this [Pixel Width of the text in a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340667/pixel-width-of-the-text-in-a-uilabel) help ?

Answer (score -1):

textField is delegate which is attac in interface builder than......

[textField.text length]