# CoreText and strikethrough on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, nsattributedstring, strikethrough, core-text

I'm currently struggling with the need to display strikethrough text in many `UITableViewCell`s. Something that written in HTML would looke like

```
<strike>€99</strike> save 50% => now €49
```

I don't want to use a `UIWebView` just for a single line of text, especially that it's used in small `UITableViewCell`s. I know there are reusable cells and all, but I'd like to keep things the more memory-efficient way possible.

So... I'm using `NSAttributedString`s, with the help of AliSoftware's `UILabel`-replacement `OHAttributedLabel`. The fact that it's only available starting with iOS 4.0 is no problem, as we use all kinds of stuff only 4.0-compatible.

I can manage to create the attributed string, it displays text in the `OHAttributedLabel`, OK, that's cool. But what I can't achieve is setting the "strikeout", or "strikethrough" attribute.

Basically I go like this:

```
NSString *price = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%01.2f €", product.price];
NSString *rate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" -%01.0f%%", product.reductionRate];

NSMutableAttributedString *s = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:price];

[s addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlinePatternSolid | NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSRangeFromString(price)];
[attributedLabel setAttributedText:s];
```

But here, the three `NS*` constants are undefined. I've imported `CoreText.h`, `Foundation/NSAttributedString.h`, to no avail. I've seen somewhere on the web that
`NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName = @"NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName"`, and that `NSUnderlinePatternSolid = 0` and `NSUnderlineStyleSingle = 1`, but hard-coding these values don't give anything.
One thing I got with auto-completion are the equivalent `kCT...*` constants, but there are `kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName`, `kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName`, ... but no mention of `kCTStrikethrough`_anything.

What should I do to display that *$|#!@ piece of strike-through text ?

Comment: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/ Works GREAT for me...enjoy!

Answer (score 7):

With iOS 6 you can use NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:selectedRange];
```

While it may seem out of place, the numberWithInt value is correct as NSUnderlineStyleSingle.

Comment: Still, if you use Core Text to render the attributed string, it will not render strikethrough line, even in iOS7.1

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach might be two labels, using the answer to this question - [Pixel Width of the text in a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340667/pixel-width-of-the-text-in-a-uilabel) - to strikeout the text in one of the labels.