# NSString value Crossout iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

How to cross out a string $127.95 in middle. Is there any simple method used to **Strike** ?

Comment: do you want to remove a substring?

Comment: Nope! i just want to strike the $127.95 value, just a cross in middle like striking that

Comment: You'll get help & answer by referring this :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550732/font-with-strike-through-it Hopefully It'll help you.<br />Thanks.

Comment: Here is your solution : http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS6 you can use `NSAttributedString`:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlinePatternSolid | NSUnderlineStyleSingle]};

NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"$127.95" attributes:attributes];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this answer:

[CoreText and strikethrough on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579270/coretext-and-strikethrough-on-iphone)

It suggests using Core Text as described here:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/

Note: this is iOS6 only.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel for dropped in `UILabel` replacement, it does all the Core Text heavy lifting pretty well.