# How to get the correct width of a UILabel after the text has been set?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm getting the width of a UILabel [after the text has been set] with:

```
myUILabel.frame.width
```

but its always the same width, no matter if it holds the String: `"Hello."` or the String: `"Hello everyone on this planet."`. But the UILabel needs to have a bigger width with the second String.

Comment: use [myUILabel sizeToFit]; also we can calculate width using like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340667/pixel-width-of-the-text-in-a-uilabel

Comment: For what do you need width? And are you using auto layout ? If you are using auto layout you can get rid of it by playing with content hugging priority so frame.width will return correct value

Comment: You could look at the intrinsic content size of a label which has to do with auto layout and layout constraints. Just google it, maybe you even actually want to use auto layout when you want to know the label's width.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try `myUILabel.intrinsicContentSize()`.  Make sure you set your font first, of course.

Comment: To get the width use: myUILabel.intrinsicContentSize.width

Comment: thank you for the help. i was trang using constratings in storyboard.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `[label sizeToFit]`

`sizeToFit` on label will stretch the label to accommodate the text.

The other solution is to calculate the width of the string and reframe the label based on the strings width.

For the second solution you can calculate the size of string as

```
CGSize strSize = CGSizeZero;

CGSize minSize = CGSizeZero;

if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
{
    NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: label.font}] autorelease];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    strSize = rect.size;
}
else
{
    strSize = [text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:constraintSize];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```swift
     myUILabel.intrinsicContentSize.width
```

Or

```swift
     myUILabel.intrinsicContentSize().width
```