# Set view width size programmatically base on it's subview

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `customView` contain some `subViews` like this:

[image]

I have set `messageLabel` trailing constraint to it's superView = 4

I want my `customView` width constraint will be set automatically base on `messageLabel`. If I create customView like this:

```
FlyingMessageDisplayView(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40))
```

how to set it's width size because messageLabel can be long or sort.

Comment: you need to it manually, first find width of label with it text  and set view size accordingly see this how to find width http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340667/pixel-width-of-the-text-in-a-uilabel

Comment: Why would you want to pass the frame if you want it to automatically resize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set my `customView` width size base on it's sub label like this

```
customView.frame.size.width = customView.messageLabelWidth + 50 // 50 here is for imageView width and some spacing.
```

where `messageLabelWidth` in `FlyingMessageDisplayView`

```
var messageLabelWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return messageLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width
    }
}
```

It will calculate the width of label first base on text length, then update width of `customView`